# How to multithread downloading and append into an external variable?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I'm trying to multithread download tickers using yfinance. After I break down the long list of tickers into smaller lists, I launch the download thread, and each download is appended to an external list.

However, when I print the list at the end, I only see 3 tickers, out of the 18 of the initial.

Here is what I did and the output below. What did I do wrong there?

```
sp500_array = sp500_tickers.copy()
sublists = np.array_split(sp500_array, 5)

multi_df = []

def thread_download(i):

    the_list = sublists[i].tolist()
    print('the_list',the_list)
    dl_df = yf.download(the_list, period ="max", start=start_date, end=datetime.now().date(), threads = True)
    multi_df.append(dl_df)

def Launch_Download_Threads():
    if __name__ != "__main__":
        return

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(thread_download, range(5))
    
    print('\nDONE, multi_df length ', len(multi_df))

Launch_Download_Threads()
```

The output is:

```
the_list ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ABMD']
the_list ['ACN', 'ATVI', 'ADBE', 'AMD']
the_list ['AAP', 'AES', 'AFL', 'A']
the_list ['APD', 'AKAM', 'ALK']
the_list ['ALB', 'ARE', 'ALGN']
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed

[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed


[*********************************************200%***********************************************]  6 of 3 completed
DONE, multi_df length  5
```

And the `print(multi_df[0])` or `print(multi_df[1])` all show only the ABBV, ABMD, ACN and AKAM tickers